# Aggregate Functions over a List in JAVA

Tags: java, database, mapreduce, data-processing

I have a list of Java Objects and I need to reduce it applying Aggregate Functions like a select over a DataBase.

NOTE: The data were calculated from multiples Databases and services calls.  I expect to have thousands of rows and each row always will have the same quantity of "cells" for each execution. This quantity changes between executions.

***Samples:***

Supposing I have my data represented in a `List` of `Object[3]` (`List<Object[]>`) my data could be:

```
[{"A", "X", 1},
{"A", "Y", 5},
{"B", "X", 1},
{"B", "X", 2}]
```

**Sample 1:**

SUM over index 2, Grouping by index 0 and 1

```
[{"A", "X", 1},
{"A", "Y", 5},
{"B", "X", 3}]
```

**Sample 2:**

MAX over index 2, Grouping by index 0

```
[{"A", "Y", 5},
{"B", "X", 2}]
```

Somebody knows about some framework or api that could emulate this behavior in Java?

My first option was insert all data in a NO-SQL database (like Couchbase), then apply the Map-Reduce and finally get the result of that. But this solution have a big overhead.

My second option was to embed a Groovy script, but it has a big overhead too.

Comment: You could use something like HSQLDB, with an in-memory DB, instead of `List<Object[]>`s.  Or, see if you can setup a DB that supports remote views to other DB products.  For instance, MSSQL server has the ability to create a remote "view" to any DB that you can create an ODBC connection too, which is pretty much all of them.  I think Oracle DB has this too, believe it's called Oracle Database Link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If Java 8 is an option then you can achieve what you want with [Stream.collect](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-).

For example:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;

public class Example
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    List<List<Object>> list = Arrays.asList(
      Arrays.<Object>asList("A", "X", 1),
      Arrays.<Object>asList("A", "Y", 5),
      Arrays.<Object>asList("B", "X", 1),
      Arrays.<Object>asList("B", "X", 2)
    );

    Map<Set<Object>, List<List<Object>>> groups = list.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Example::newGroup));

    System.out.println(groups);

    Map<Set<Object>, Integer> sums = list.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Example::newGroup, summingInt(Example::getInt)));

    System.out.println(sums);

    Map<Set<Object>, Optional<List<Object>>> max = list.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Example::newGroup, maxBy(Example::compare)));

    System.out.println(max);
  }

  private static Set<Object> newGroup(List<Object> item)
  {
    return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(item.get(0), item.get(1)));
  }

  private static Integer getInt(List<Object> items)
  {
    return (Integer)items.get(2);
  }

  private static int compare(List<Object> items1, List<Object> items2)
  {
    return (((Integer)items1.get(2)) - ((Integer)items2.get(2)));
  }
}
```

Gives the following output:

```
{[A, X]=[[A, X, 1]], [B, X]=[[B, X, 1], [B, X, 2]], [A, Y]=[[A, Y, 5]]}

{[A, X]=1, [B, X]=3, [A, Y]=5}

{[A, X]=Optional[[A, X, 1]], [B, X]=Optional[[B, X, 2]], [A, Y]=Optional[[A, Y, 5]]}
```

Alternatively, using the Java 8 example as inspiration, while a bit more verbose, you can achieve the same thing in older versions of Java like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Example
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    List<List<Object>> list = Arrays.asList(
      Arrays.<Object>asList("A", "X", 1),
      Arrays.<Object>asList("A", "Y", 5),
      Arrays.<Object>asList("B", "X", 1),
      Arrays.<Object>asList("B", "X", 2)
    );

    Function<List<Object>, Set<Object>> groupBy = new Function<List<Object>, Set<Object>>()
    {
      @Override
      public Set<Object> apply(List<Object> item)
      {
        return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(item.get(0), item.get(1)));
      }
    };

    Map<Set<Object>, List<List<Object>>> groups = group(
      list,
      groupBy
    );

    System.out.println(groups);

    Map<Set<Object>, Integer> sums = sum(
      list,
      groupBy,
      new Function<List<Object>, Integer>()
      {
        @Override
        public Integer apply(List<Object> item)
        {
          return (Integer)item.get(2);
        }
      }
    );

    System.out.println(sums);

    Map<Set<Object>, List<Object>> max = max(
      list,
      groupBy,
      new Comparator<List<Object>>()
      {
        @Override
        public int compare(List<Object> items1, List<Object> items2)
        {
          return (((Integer)items1.get(2)) - ((Integer)items2.get(2)));
        }
      }
    );

    System.out.println(max);

  }

  public static <K, V> Map<K, List<V>> group(Collection<V> items, Function<V, K> groupFunction)
  {
    Map<K, List<V>> groupedItems = new HashMap<>();

    for (V item : items)
    {
      K key = groupFunction.apply(item);

      List<V> itemGroup = groupedItems.get(key);
      if (itemGroup == null)
      {
        itemGroup = new ArrayList<>();
        groupedItems.put(key, itemGroup);
      }

      itemGroup.add(item);
    }

    return groupedItems;
  }

  public static <K, V> Map<K, Integer> sum(Collection<V> items, Function<V, K> groupFunction, Function<V, Integer> intGetter)
  {
    Map<K, Integer> sums = new HashMap<>();

    for (V item : items)
    {
      K key = groupFunction.apply(item);
      Integer sum = sums.get(key);

      sums.put(key, sum != null ? sum + intGetter.apply(item) : intGetter.apply(item));
    }

    return sums;
  }

  public static <K, V> Map<K, V> max(Collection<V> items, Function<V, K> groupFunction, Comparator<V> comparator)
  {
    Map<K, V> maximums = new HashMap<>();

    for (V item : items)
    {
      K key = groupFunction.apply(item);
      V maximum = maximums.get(key);

      if (maximum == null || comparator.compare(maximum, item) < 0)
      {
        maximums.put(key, item);
      }
    }

    return maximums;
  }

  private static interface Function<T, R>
  {
    public R apply(T value);
  }
}
```

Gives the following output:

```
{[A, X]=[[A, X, 1]], [A, Y]=[[A, Y, 5]], [B, X]=[[B, X, 1], [B, X, 2]]}

{[A, X]=1, [A, Y]=5, [B, X]=3}

{[A, X]=[A, X, 1], [A, Y]=[A, Y, 5], [B, X]=[B, X, 2]}
```

Comment: It looks like an good option! Unfortunately I am using java 6 :/ Thanks!

Comment: @DiegoD it's more work in older version of Java, but still possible - I've added an example.  When I've had requirements like this in the past I normally write a MapUtils class containing the variable methods, though more recently Guava offers similar functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Use an in-memory SQL database like SQL lite, H2, Derby or some other. Create a table matching the elements of each row. Populate it with the results of querying different data sets. Then query the in memory table with whatever sorting and grouping options you need.

I agree it maybe a bit overkill to use the in-memory database just for that, but the code will be much more readable and RDBMS's are made for these kinds of queries.

Comment: Also, writing the data directly to an in-memory table would probably be little more overhead than creating huge in-memory `List<Object[]>`s with some crazy API/Library to simulate what a DB can do anyhow.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, i will try it. I am thinking to use H2, but recently I found a Comparison with ObjectDB and it could be a good option too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use a third party library and don't need parallelism, then [jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) offers aggregation utilities on top of standard JDK `Stream` and `Collectors`

#### Sample 1:

```java
Map<Tuple2<Object, Object>, Optional<Object>> map = 
Seq.seq(list)
   .groupBy(a -> tuple(a[0], a[1]), Agg.sum(a -> a[2]));

System.out.println(map);
```

Yielding

```
{(B, X)=Optional[3], 
 (A, X)=Optional[1], 
 (A, Y)=Optional[5]}
```

#### Sample 2:

```java
Map<Object, Optional<Integer>> map = 
Seq.seq(list)
   .groupBy(a -> a[0], Agg.max(a -> (Integer) a[2]));

System.out.println(map);
```

Yielding

```
{A=Optional[5], B=Optional[2]}
```

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOλ

Comment: hey @lukas-eder, is jOOλ still under active development?

Comment: @AnotherGoodGuy: I'd do 1-2 things if they're compelling, sure

Comment: I mean is it uptodate for JDK@17 and above

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, @lukas-eder, I meant, is it up to date for JDK@17 and above

Comment: @AnotherGoodGuy: Yes. If not: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL/issues/new